# How to add prefix to layer in WriteOGR when writing to multiple files

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sp

How would one add prefix in the layer option in writeOGR?

I have tried `layer=c("poly_", code)` but it doesn't work

Nicolai

Comment: Use `paste0("poly_", code)`

Comment: thanks :-) That did the trick...